# low search by fields with relationship

Tags: search, relationships, low-search

I tried to use all possible way for search but it doesn't work.

So what I have:

Channel **countries**:

- field: country_name (like UK, USA, Ireland, Russia and etc)

Channel **departments**:

- field: department_title (like tech, commerce, finance)

Channels **careers**:

- field: title
- field: careers_department_title(relationship with channel **departments** by field department_title)
- field: career_role_location(relationship with channel **countries** by field country_name)

To display all from careers I do:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="careers"}
  Job title - {title}
  Department title: {careers_department_title:department_title:}
  Role location: {career_role_location:country_name}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Now I need to do search by country or by departments.

```
{exp:low_search:filters query="USA"}
  {exp:channel:entries channel="careers" style="linear"}
   {career__country_name:country_name}
  {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:low_search:filters}
```

As result I have list of all countries, but I need only from specific country, in this example should be only USA, and no UK, Russia and other.

Can somebody advice how correctly to write this search by field which has relationship type?

My main goal to display dropdown menu and user can select search option: search by departments or by location.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of things here. I don't think you need the Preparse option as Jeremy suggested, as you can filter by country/department ID, not by their actual names. Here's what to do:

#### Results tag

Use something like this in your Results tag:

```
{exp:low_search:results channel="careers" query="{segment_3}"}
  code to display careers here
{/exp:low_search:results}
```

Make sure `{segment_3}` points to the **encoded query** in the URI. Something like `query="USA"` like you tried **will not work**.

#### Create a search form

In that form, you can let the user choose a country or department. Something like this:

```
{exp:low_search:form result_page="search/results"}

  <select name="child:the_country_relationship_field">
    <option value="">Select country</option>
    {exp:channel:entries channel="countries" dynamic="no"}
      <option value="{entry_id}">{country_name}</option>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
  </select>

  <select name="child:the_department_relationship_field">
    <option value="">Select department</option>
    {exp:channel:entries channel="departments" dynamic="no"}
      <option value="{entry_id}">{department_name}</option>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
  </select>

  <button type="submit">Search!</button>

{/exp:low_search:form}
```

Make sure that you replace `the_country_relationship_field` and `the_department_relationship_field` with their corresponding relationship field names.

This combination should give you the filtered results.

Comment: It works exactly what I need. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Low How do i get search keywords in the result page when i do relationship search

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method may be to use Solspace's free [Preparse](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/preparse/) extension. It's a bit of a hidden gem. It essentially parses a template based on an entry id and stores it in a text field in the entry.

Low actually [blogged](http://gotolow.com/blog/searching-non-field-data-with-low-search) about how to use Preparse with Low Search to make categories searchable. The same could be done for any fieldtype that doesn't use the standard `exp_channel_data` fields to store its data, such as a relationship or Playa field.

Comment: The main resean why I purchased low search is possibility to do search in fields with type: relationship. I cannot understand how links in your answer can help in my situation.